# Folland ex. 1.3 #8

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measure space and $\{A_j\}\subset \mathcal{M}$ prove that $\mu(\limsup A_i) \geq \limsup \mu(A_i)$ provided that $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_j)<\infty$. What happens if $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_j)<\infty$ does not hold?

Attempt:We have $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=i}^{\infty}A_k) \geq \mu(A_n)$ for $n \geq i$. Taking $i \to \infty$ and using continuity from above, we have $\mu(\limsup A_i)=\lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=i}^{\infty}A_k)\geq \limsup \mu(A_i)$.

I do not know what would happen if $\mu(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_j)<\infty$ does not hold. Any help?

Would this condition obstruct the continuity from above?

Comment: You should add the extra step: Why can you use continuity from above?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski would it be because each $\mu(A_i)$ is finite?

Comment: Well, what does the theorem say? You should not guess this, but rather check it. I'd be happy to help with the details if you do so.

Comment: Here is a hint: Let $F_{k}=\bigcup_{i=k}^{\infty}A_{i}$ what can you then say about the sequence $(F_{j})$? Can you use continuity from above with this sequence?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski yes because $F_1 \supset F_2 \supset F_3 \supset \cdots$?

Comment: And... (There is another assumption needed)

Comment: @AndréArmatowski $\mu(F_1)<\infty$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129339/discussion-between-andre-armatowski-and-tasso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the real line with Lebsgue measure $\mu$. If $A_i=(i,i+1)$ then $\lim \sup A_i$ is empty and $\mu(A_i)=1$ for all $i$. So this is a  counter-example when $\mu \cup A_i)$ is not assumed to be finite.

Your proof for the first case is a bit messed up. You should write

$\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=i}^{\infty}A_k) \geq \mu(A_i)$ for $i$. Taking $i \to \infty$ and using continuity from above, we have $\mu(\limsup A_i)=\lim\limits_{i \to \infty}\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=i}^{\infty}A_k)\geq \limsup \mu(A_i)$.

Comment: If $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined on borel sets can i take $A_i=(i,i+\delta)$, where $\delta \in [0,1]$ and then would $\mu(A_i)=\delta$ necessarily?

Comment: That is assuming $\mu(\mathbb{R})< \infty$ does not hold?

Comment: @Tasso Yes, I have edited my answer.